# Metrics for any step of Sagemaker pipeline (not just TrainingStep)

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, mlops

My understanding is that in order to compare different trials of a pipeline (see image), the metrics can only be obtained from the `TrainingStep`, using the `metric_definitions` argument for an `Estimator`.

[image: screenshot]

In my pipeline, I extract metrics in the evaluation step that follows the training. Is it possible to record there metrics that are then tracked for each trial?

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker suggests using [Property Files and JsonGet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-propertyfile.html) for each necessary step. This approach is suitable for using conditional steps within the pipeline, but also trivially for persisting results somewhere.

```py
from sagemaker.workflow.properties import PropertyFile
from sagemaker.workflow.steps import ProcessingStep

evaluation_report = PropertyFile(
    name="EvaluationReport",
    output_name="evaluation",
    path="evaluation.json"
)

step_eval = ProcessingStep(
     # ...
     property_files=[evaluation_report]
)
```

and in your processor script:

```py
import json

report_dict = {}  # your report
evaluation_path = "/opt/ml/processing/evaluation/evaluation.json"

with open(evaluation_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(report_dict))
```

You can read this file in the pipeline steps directly with [JsonGet](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#sagemaker.workflow.functions.JsonGet).

Comment: edited the post to explain better what I'm after

Comment: In the processing components, there does not seem to be the possibility of defining metrics. A possible solution is to add a component made specifically for conducting analysis on the results. See ["Amazon SageMaker Clarify Detects Bias and Increases the Transparency of Machine Learning Models"](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/aws/new-amazon-sagemaker-clarify-detects-bias-and-increases-the-transparency-of-machine-learning-models/). Personally, I follow the approach written in the answer and that is what AWS also recommends in the various example notebooks.