# How to display metrics and value on SageMaker pipeline UI?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Run a SageMaker pipeline from SageMaker studio, each pipeline step (e.g., ProcessingStep, TrainingStep, LambdaStep) has an output tab,

[image]

I tried to search for the SDK doc, but couldn't find anything related.  How may I display metrics from custom processing, training or lambda containers to the tab?

Answer (score 0):

### For built-in algorithms

In the case of built-in algorithms, I refer to the official "[Define Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-define-metrics.html)" guide (chapter "Using a built-in algorithm for training").

### For Custom algorithms

The problem is solved basically in 2 steps:

1. Within your script (e.g., the training script) you will need to log
   the metric to intercept.

   Trivially a print/log:

   ```py
   print(f"New best val_loss score: {your_metric}")
   ```
2. Within the definition of your pipeline component you should set the `metric_definitions` parameter.

   For example in [Estimators](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html).

> **metric_definitions** (list[dict[str, str] or list[dict[str,
> PipelineVariable]]) – A list of dictionaries that defines the
> metric(s) used to evaluate the training jobs. Each dictionary contains
> two keys: ‘Name’ for the name of the metric, and ‘Regex’ for the
> regular expression used to extract the metric from the logs. This
> should be defined only for jobs that don’t use an Amazon algorithm.

To use it for the above example, it will then suffice to define:

```py
metric_definitions=[
    {'Name': 'val_loss', 'Regex': 'New best val_loss score: ([0-9\.]+)'}
]
```

P.S.: Remember that estimators also mean derived classes such as [SKLearn](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/sagemaker.sklearn.html), [PyTorch](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/sagemaker.pytorch.html), etc...

---

At this point, at the reference step where you have defined the metrics to be intercepted, you will find a key-value pair, of the **last value intercepted**, in the **SageMaker Studio** screen and also a graph to monitor progress (even during training) in cloudwatch metrics.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense for `Estimator` and I'll give it a try.  How about other steps like `ProcessorStep` or `LambdaStep`, I didn't find a `metric_definitions` for those APIs.

Comment: You may find it useful to read this related question: [Metrics for any step of Sagemaker pipeline (not just TrainingStep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304758/metrics-for-any-step-of-sagemaker-pipeline-not-just-trainingstep)

Comment: @GiuseppeLaGualano So it's not possible except for an `Estimator` basically?